# extending User model using django-username-email Package

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am quite a beginner in django and I would really need your help.. 
I am trying to extends the User model provided by Django in order to log in a user only using Email and pass and not a username

For that I am using the great package https://pypi.org/project/django-username-email that give a really easy way to do it.

However I would like to extend it as well in order to add field such as 'job'

I tried to do it that way but it does not help me to progress toward my goal.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
# Create your models here.

User = get_user_model()


class CustomUser(User):
    position = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
```

Could you please help me extend an extended UserModel ? 
Thx you

Answer (score 0):

For extending your model you can inherit only `abstract` model. For your current purpose you should inherit `AbstractBaseUser`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    position = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
```

Comment: But will it take into account as well my current user model that I got using User = get_user_model() and the package ?

Comment: could not understand what you said, If you want to register `CustomUser`  model as your user model you should set it is settings 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.model_name'`

Comment: right now I already extended the UserModel using the package django-username-email but I need to exetend it more ..

Comment: If you want to include the fields defined in `django-username-email` in customuser model then you should define these fields in an AbstractModel.  for making any model as AbstractModel just set abstract as True in meta class.